# Windows 10 - VB 5.2.4 with Ubuntu 16.04: Sending files between two VMs with Python

Tags: python, virtual-machine, virtualbox, sendfile

I'm new to python and this time I want to send a file between two VMs, first of all, the VMs are configured with NAT Network, both VMs can ping each other. The codes are the following:

Server side:

```
#server.py

import socket                   # Import socket module

port = 60000                    # Reserve a port for your service.
s = socket.socket()             # Create a socket object
host = socket.gethostname()     # Get local machine name
# s.bind((host, port))            # Bind to the port
s.bind(('', port))
s.listen(5)                     # Now wait for client connection.

print 'Server listening....'

while True:
conn, addr = s.accept()     # Establish connection with client.
print 'Got connection from', addr
data = conn.recv(1024)
print('Server received', repr(data))

filename='runbonesi.py'
f = open(filename,'rb')
l = f.read(1024)
while (l):
   conn.send(l)
   print('Sent ',repr(l))
   l = f.read(1024)
f.close()

print('Done sending')
conn.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
print conn.recv(1024)
conn.close()
```

client side:

```
#client.py
import socket                   # Import socket module

s = socket.socket()             # Create a socket object
#host = socket.gethostname()     # Get local machine name
host = '10.0.2.15'
port = 60000                    # Reserve a port for your service.

s.connect((host, port))

with open('received_file', 'wb') as f:
print 'file opened'
while True:
    print('receiving data...')
    data = s.recv(1024)
    print('data=%s', (data))
    if not data:
        break
    # write data to a file
    f.write(data)

f.close()
print('Successfully get the file')
s.close()
print('connection closed')
```

The results can be seen in the following pictures:

Server side:
[result on server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHAEz.png)

Client side:
[result on client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKQcf.png)

The problem is, the client didn't receive the file as .py format, it only received as txt files. Please help me resolve this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly the issue is?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When you created your account here, it was suggested you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the [help center pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help) in order to familiarize yourself with the site. Specific pages that you should read include [How Do I Ask a Good Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please take these introductory steps and then edit your post accordingly.

Comment: A first thing I notice is that the sever after establishing the connection with the client it tries to read "something" from the client `print 'Got connection from', addr` `data = conn.recv(1024)`, but the client it's not sending anything, it just starts to read too. So you either comment "the read" on the server or "send" something from the client.

Comment: @NestorYanchuk I'm sorry, I edited the questions. The client didn't received the exact "runbonesi.py", it only received a txt file, the content is the same though..

Answer (score 0):

After `s.connect((host, port))` in the client script you have to write `s.send(...)` with 'hello', for example. You also forgot to write the file extension '.py' in `with open(...)` (only if you want to save the file as Python script!). And you also have to add `s.send(...)` before you close the connection on the client side.